# How to convert array defined in string variable with \r\n using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable with array data .

```
var str = "[\r\n  10,\r\n  20\r\n]" ;
```

I want to convert above string to array like using javascript .

Output :-

```
var  arr  = [10,20];
```

Comment: `var arr = eval(str)` ?

Comment: Just do `var arr = JSON.parse(str)`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) - it will ignore the newlines and convert the string representation of an array to a JavaScript array:

```js
var str = "[\r\n  10,\r\n  20\r\n]" ;

var arr = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(Array.isArray(arr))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: To be more exact regarding the [JSON specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) `Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any token. Whitespace is any sequence of one or more of
the following code points: character tabulation (U+0009), line feed (U+000A), carriage return (U+000D), and
space (U+0020). Whitespace is not allowed within any token, except that space is allowed in strings.`

Answer (score -1):

You need only to parse that string as a JSON, because it is clearly an array.

So this is the procedure:

```js
var str = "[\r\n  10,\r\n  20\r\n]";

const myArray = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(myArray);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are wondering why those special chars (`\r\n`) are going away:

```js
// a string
const str = "[\r\n  10,\r\n  20\r\n]";

// if I print out this, Javascript, will automatically replace those special
// chars with what they means (new line)
console.log(str);
console.log(typeof(str));

// so if we are going to parse our string to the JSON parser
// it will automatically transform the special chars to new lines
// and then convert the result string "[10,20]" to an array.
const myArray = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(myArray);
console.log(typeof(myArray));
```